# fail to remove shapes and body from space using cocos-js chipmunk

Tags: javascript, chipmunk, cocos2d-js

I am quite new to cocos2d-js and I am trying to remove the shape and body with
a simple demo but failed .

```
        var body = new cp.Body(1,cp.momentForBox(1,20,20));
    body.setPos(cc.p(100,300));
    this._space.addBody(body);
    var shape=cp.BoxShape(body,20,20);
    shape.setElasticity(0.5);
    shape.setFriction(0.8);
    this._space.addShape(shape);

    var shapeList = body.shapeList;shapeList[0]=null;
    body.removeShape(shapeList[0]);
    console.log(shapeList);
    this._space.removeBody(body);
```

I get confused totally.

Comment: It would be great if you can include a fully working (or rather, failing) demo. You can use a site like codepen.io for that.

Comment: I put my project at  http://zen1995.github.io/cocos2d-js_demo/    and you can see the code at https://github.com/zen1995/cocos2d-js_demo

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your code and I saw that the shape and body are removed correctly, so the problems are not from here. You have errors on github code. Check the code very carefully. This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this part,

```
shapeList[0] = null
```

it is a ref to shape in the list. You define it null so it remove nothing.